# useDelimiter() printing empty space

Tags: java, regex, string, java.util.scanner

I have a string, `String url = "www.public.website.edu/~JohnSmith/JAVA000";`. I aim to use delimiters to get the desired output as shown below.

I do *kinda* get the ouput, but there seems to be an extra line that's printed and I'm not entirely sure where it comes from.

Code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "www.public.website.edu/~JohnSmith/JAVA000";
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(url);
        scan.useDelimiter("[./~]");
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(scan.next());
        }
```

Actual:

```
www
public
website
edu

JohnSmith
JAVA000
```

Expected:

```
www
public
website
edu
JohnSmith
JAVA000
```

I'm not entirely sure where my regex syntax is going wrong.

Comment: It seems like it's printing empty string because that's the value  between the two delimeters / and ~. Might be easier to use Guava splitter: `Splitter.onPattern("[./~]").omitEmptyStrings().split("www.public.website.edu/~JohnSmith/JAVA000") `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`next` will keep reading the string you gave the scanner, until a delimiter is found, and return the string that is read.

Let's see what happens just after the scanner has read `edu`. The scanner's position is now at:

```
www.public.website.edu/~JohnSmith/JAVA000
                      ^
```

It starts reading by going to the next character. It sees that the next character `~` is also a delimiter, as it matches the `[./~]` regex, so it stops here. What non-delimiter character has the scanner read? None! So `next` returns an empty string, and you print that empty string, which causes the empty line to appear.

If you don't like the empty line, you can specify that a delimiter is *one or more of the characters in* `[./~]` by using the `+` quantifier:

```
scan.useDelimiter("[./~]+");
```

This way, `/~` is treated as *one* delimiter, rather than 2 separate ones.

Comment: assuming id only want to extract letters and numbers, with all other symbols out, to combat the effect of two or more non-alphanumeric characters being together, i'd have to use the "+" operator? insightful! thank you very much

Comment: @simonshampoo If you only want letters and numbers, you can use the regex `[^a-zA-Z0-9]+` as the delimiter. It means "everything except letters and numbers, repeated one or more times."